# What is ActiveRecord::Relation really?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Deal class( Its called a model right?) like this.

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And I can apply the methods of [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) in
Deal class
i.e `Deal.destroy_all` and also something like `Deal.where(id: 1).destroy_all`.
I get the `Deal.where(id: 1)` part since it return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But what about `Deal.destroy_all`. I don't think it is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

What am I getting wrong?
**EDIT**
Any help would be appreciated. Really. You could direct me to a blog or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we call `ActiveRecord` class methods, Rails will call `:all` on that if it it's not loaded.

That means `Deal.destroy_all` is same as `Deal.all.destroy_all` and `Deal.all.class` is `ActiveRecord::Relation` of course.

```
def destroy_all
  records.each(&:destroy).tap { reset }
end

def records
  load
  @records
end

def load(&block)
  exec_queries(&block) unless loaded?

  self
end

def all
  if current_scope
    current_scope.clone
  else
    default_scoped
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `Deal` here? Its inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` right? So does that mean that all `ActiveRecord::Base` class methods apply `:all` before.

Comment: So if I'm doing something like Deal.where(id: 2), it actually means Deal.all.where(id: 2) right?

Comment: I've just figured out, Rails 3 will call `:scoped` instead of `:all`

Comment: And the purposes are the same.